# Rollback Salesforce deployment using Jenkins CI

Tags: git, jenkins, salesforce, continuous-deployment

I tried to automate salesforce org-based deployment by running Jenkins CI [using Salesforce CLI]. However, I also want to try rolling back a false deployment using Jenkins. Though using version control systems like Git help me to maintain backup and reference for commits, I am unable to figure out how to do a proper rollback using Git/other SCMs. Suppose say,

Example: from sandbox1 to sandbox2 I deployed a project package **'X'** having version 1.1 but later I found some issue with the deployment and I want to rollback to 1.0 version in between the wrongly deployed components in target org sandbox2 should be removed automatically after building Jenkins pipeline. Through backup from version control like GIT, I can re-deploy version 1.0 but can't delete the wrongly deployed components of 1.1 from sandbox2 using pipeline

Even ant-deployment or using destructivechanges.xml can't help me because I need to manually write that file.
find a similar SO question [Automatize manual tasks after deployment of Salesforce project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39039136/automatize-manual-tasks-after-deployment-of-salesforce-project) but didn't get what I want.

Is there any way I can automate deployment rollback using Jenkins CI? Please guide me on this

Thanks in advance!!!